# Wordpress Custom field doesn't update DB consistently

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a custom field on user-edit admin page. I added the custom code to functions.php.

**Problem:** Sometimes it updates the db and sometimes it doesn't update the db.

I thought it was caching but it's not that.  Can someone tell me why it would be updating sometimes but not all the time?  Do you see a problem with my code?

**Code:**

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'be_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'be_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function be_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="contact">Phone</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'phone', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
                <span class="description">Enter phone number.</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php } 
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'be_save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'be_save_extra_profile_fields' );

function be_save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'phone', esc_attr( $_POST['phone'] ) );
}
```

**UPDATE**

I now know why the admin form updates the db sometimes and sometimes it does not update the db. The admin form has a phone field plus on the profile page there's  phone field also.  When I updated the phone in admin and refreshed the page on the profile page it updated it when the textbox was not filled in.  When the textbox was filled in and I updated the form in admin, refreshing the profile page would insert the phone number from the profile page.  So there's an issue with the profile page, it inserts data on refresh.

Comment: Read the *note* section in the description in the Codex. https://codex.wordpress.org/edit_user_profile_update. You need to change the `$_POST['phone']` to something unique like `$_POST['phone_data']`

Comment: Thanks for that information.  I've tried many different names including the one you posted and does the same thing.  But I found out what the problem is.  I'll post the issue....

Answer (score 0):

I now know why the admin form updates the db sometimes and sometimes it does not update the db. The admin form has a phone field plus on the profile page there's phone field also. When I updated the phone in admin and refreshed the page on the profile page it updated it when the textbox was not filled in. When the textbox was filled in and I updated the form in admin, refreshing the profile page would insert the phone number from the profile page. So there's an issue with the profile page, it inserts data on refresh.  The admin form was updating the db.  The profile form was making it seem it was not updating because when refreshed it would update the db with that value.